# How to call an instance method defined in a module that is overwritten by another module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module, mixins

```
class Person
  include Voice
  include Beep
end

module Voice
  def speak
    puts 'speaking from module'
  end

  def original_speak
    # ???
  end
end

module Beep
  def speak
    puts 'beep beep'
  end
end
```

How to call `Voice#speak`? For example:

```
Person.new.voice_speak
```

I want to add this code to the Voice module, not the Person class or the Beep module.

Use case:
A module that does soft delete:

```
module Undeletable
  def delete
    # mark document as deleted. This creates a deletion document.
  end

  def restore
    # Delete (for real) the deletion.
  end

  def obliterate
    restore # because we don't want orphaned deletions.

    real_delete # This should call Mongoid#delete
  end
end

def Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Undeletable
end
```

So, in general, when we call foo.delete, we want to soft delete. However, in rare cases, we want to do a real delete. The module should support both methods.

Comment: If it can't be done easily then it might be wrong to do it. What is your use case?

Comment: What's going on? You've changed the question, making both answers nonsensical. I suggest you roll back. Your original question was fine, interesting.  (Downvote not mine.)

Comment: Haha, I thought someone would ask. Your answer was deleted and I had already implemented the answer from Pascal. The answer didn't work for me because the question was different.

Comment: I've removed my answer because it does not make sense now that you updated the question.

Comment: However, out of respect for you and Pascal, I can roll it back and make a new one, if you want.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Tried to roll back, but it seems like it is not possible since I asked the question. If you want to roll it back that is fine with me. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: for the most part, only by calling `super` in the over-ridden implementation. There are probably hacks to do it otherwise, you can hack most anything in ruby, but don't.  You can not call the superclass version of an overridden method, except from the override implementation. Name the method something else, or conditonally call `super` in it when you want the superclass implementation. Those are your options.

Answer (score 1):

Readers: I posted this answer to the original question. The question was subsequently changed. If interested, check the edit history for context.

The steps are as follows.

- Create a callback in module `Voice` that is invoked when the module is included in `Person`. The (class) method for that is [Module#included](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included), which has one argument, the class including the module.
- `Included` creates an alias `original_speak`of `Person.speak` (in `Person`). This must be done first, while `Person#speak` is the method `speak` originally defined on `Person`.
- `Included` then removes the (original) instance method `Person#speak`, using [Module#remove_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-remove_method) (not [Module#undef_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method)), causing `Person#speak` to become the instance method `Voice#speak`, which was in effect, right "behind" the original `Person#speak` prior to the latter's removal.

```
module Voice
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send(:alias_method, :original_speak, :speak)
    klass.send(:remove_method, :speak)
  end
  def speak
    puts 'speaking from module'
  end
end

class Person
  def speak
    puts 'speaking from class'
  end
  include Voice
end

Person.instance_method(:speak).owner
  #=> Voice 
Person.instance_method(:original_speak).owner
  #=> Person 
Person.ancestors
  #=> [Person, Voice, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 

person = Person.new

person.original_speak
speaking from class

person.speak
speaking from module
```

Comment: If both, the included module and the class contain the same method, then the one defined on the class will be used. It's neither lost nor overwritten.

Comment: @pascalbetz, yes, thanks. Readers: Pascal, was referring to an incorrect explanation I gave for an answer that I subsequently revised.

Answer (score 1):

I see the easiest way as being to add a parameter to the function which overwrites `delete`. For example:

```
module Undeletable
  def delete(call_super=false)
   return super if call_super
   return "some custom response"
  end

  def obliterate
    delete(true)
  end
end
```

The `super` keyword is important here. If a method is overwritten by another, the original can be called by `super`. It's also possible to pass arguments to `super`.